# How to vertical block a column with an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, vertical-alignment

I´m havin issues with blocking the whole height of the screen. I made this navbar and want it to look like it´s "floating" on the page, by adding some margin around ist, so it´s not touching the border of the screen.
Using the `height: 100%` prop won´t work, bc I the margin won´t get attached at the bottom of the screen -> First it goes all the way down the screen, so that I have to scroll down a bit until the margin gets added + the following content does not appear to the right, but underneath the sidebar -> watch the image.

So I basically want this thing to be in a vertical div element for example, so that the next element will be next to the right of the navbar (right now the text "TEST" still is underneath the navbar).
I´m also using TailwindCSS, those are my classes attached to the wrapping div of the navbar:

```
import SidebarHeader from './sidebarHeader';
import SidebarMenu from './SidebarMenu';

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ height: '100vh' }}
      className=" m-5 rounded-2xl bg-primary w-80 border-l-4 border-primary transition duration-500 pl-5 py-5">
      <SidebarHeader />
      <SidebarMenu />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

App code:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './assets/tailwind.css';

import Sidebar from './page-components/sidebar';
import Header from './page-components/header';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Sidebar />
      <Header />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;

// Header code
//const Header = () => {
//  return <div>TEST</div>;
//};
//
//export default Header;
```

[image]

I could do a grid layout I guess, but I don´t know if that´s the smartest solution. There must be a way to have smth like a vertical block element or not?

Glad for any help I can get- cheers!

Comment: This is a HTML and CSS problem, despite the fact that the HTML is produced via React and JavaScript. Could you post the "*[mcve]*"  HTML, CSS (and relevant) JavaScript instead of the React components?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use css calc like `height: calc(100vh - XXpx)` and then you can add margins to it - sum of bottom and top margins must be equal to XXpx you defined earlier.
2. Or just wrap the sidebar in a parent component with some padding `{ height: 100vh; padding: XXpx}; display: flex;`, with display flex. Child should have a flex-grow property set to 1.

To put something next to the sidebar, both elements should have `display: inline-block; vertical-aligh: top` in that case the second solution would not work unless you wrapp the sidebar parent + aside content in a wrapper div with `display: flex` property.

Comment: Oh dam, of course I can just wrap it in a flex container et voila... Way too obvious, thanks a lot!